# How to identify device using flash actionscript3?

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, ipad

How can I get to know that the device is iphone or ipad using actionscript3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Capabilities class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html

There's no 100% method to test if something is a specific device (Adobe say to not do it), mainly because you can end up with a ball of spaghetti code that's not future proof (e.g. the resolution/dpi roughly doubled between the iPhone 3GS and the iPhone 4, and who can say what the iPhone 5/6 etc will have).

What you could use are `cpuArchitecture`, `manufacturer`, `os`, `pixelAspectRatio`, `screenDPI`, `screenResolutionX`, `screenResolutionY` and `touchscreenType` to help try and figure it out.

There's also `ContextMenu.isSupported` as the context menu (what shows when you right-click on a swf) doesn't show up on smart phones or tablets (no right-click)